# USB power is always on

Tags: windows-10, usb, power

Recently my Acer desktop (Windows 10) has started keeping power on to USB devices even when the computer is switched off. I've made no changes, just the usual MS updates that can't be stopped.

How can I get it to go back so that USB power is off when the computer is off?

Comment: In Disk Management, right-click the USB device(s) and select Properties. In Power Management tab, is "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" checked?

Comment: Are you sure that wasn't already the case before when it was powered off? AFAIK USB-power-when-off is typically intended by default by design. Some BIOS setups may offer options to disable it though.

Comment: @lmoly It defiantly was not doing it until last week, I have a 4x4x4 64 LED Cube [link](https://hobbycomponents.com/our-brand-exclusives/655-316-hobby-components-4x4x4-64-led-cube-kit-blue#/212-colour-blue) plugged into a USB port and it powered off when the PC was shut down, now it stays on unless I unplug it.

Comment: Check your bios for usb power settings.

Comment: @harrymc "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" is checked

Comment: @lmoly there is nothing I can see in the BIOS

Comment: In the Power Options applet, what is your power plan?

Comment: @James: Any BIOS options with S4, S5 or ErP in it?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, it was Windows fast boot. When this was disabled the USB ports powered down when the computer was turned off.